# Call Log breakdown per number called

Tags: excel, formula

So i have a call log in excel, it's set up something like this:

```
Inbound Phone Number:    Direction:

   8881234567                    IN
   8881234567                    IN
   8777654321                   OUT
```

Etc. Etc.

I want to set up a function to count each number, but only for incoming calls.

I was able to get =COUNTIF(A2:A1955, "8881234567")

But that obviously doesn't handle if the call is incoming or outgoing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `COUNTIFS` (with an extra "S") for multi-conditional counting in Excel 2007 or later, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,8881234567,B:B,"In")`

If you don't want to include all the numbers in the formula just list all the different numbers in D2 down and use this formula in E2 copied down

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,"In")`